# Restore <WinBase.h>

Tags: c++, windows

I was an idiot and edited WinBase.h to try and override a VC++ 2008 error. As a result, it now tries to compile WinBase whenever I compile my project. It proceeds to find upwards of 400 errors.  Stupid question: how can I fix this?

EDIT:

As it turns out, I didn't edit anything.  I just tried to `#include <WinBase.h>` instead of `#include <windows.h>`.  That doesn't work...

Comment: Maybe not changing files you don't understand to fix errors you don't understand would be the better option? :)

Comment: Blessed is the pessimist, for they are the ones who make frequent backups. I sincerely hope you have that folder backed up somewhere, and that the file can be restored with original creation-date. Otherwise start cracking open .cab files or reinstalling.

Comment: Let me get this straight... you edit a *WINDOWS HEADER FILE* to prevent *ERRORS* (that are almost certainly your fault) and you're surprised that things don't work? And your solution is "how do I not include this critical include file because I borked it?"

Comment: Alright, alright guys, we all do silly things sometimes (though some more so than others...).  Everyone starts somewhere.

Comment: @emartel True.  However, I'm looking for an answer now, not for the future.  will I ever be able to compile ANYTHING on this machine anymore?  it's in an sdk, there has to be an installer for it somewhere.

Comment: @CodeMonkey2: Did you read my response?  There certainly is an installer.

Answer (score 4):

Ummm... don't do that?  I'm not sure why you felt this was a reasonable option, but randomly taking action, especially in areas of code that you do not understand, is never a solution.

You need to reinstall it obviously.  You can install the Windows SDK again (or VC++, I'm sure
that includes it as well), that should do it for you. Now stop deleting random files *written by the creators of your operating system* in a misguided attempt to fix *your* code :)

Comment: What? I shouldn't do that sort of thing? Why, just the other day I cut this useless rubber hose in my car's engine bay. The stupid car popped a check engine light hours later. So I took the light bulb out so I don't have to take the car to a mechanic!

Comment: @NikBougalis: Don't forget to remove the engine as well, it's bound to act up sooner or later.

Comment: Imagine my fuel economy once I get rid of 500-some pounds of useless stuff ;)

Comment: @NikBougalis: Brilliant!